# Low performance when connecting HDMI display to laptop

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with XFCE
I enjoy playing Factorio in spare time.
When I run it on the laptop monitor it works great, CPU usage is high and it is turbo boosting.
When I connect a display over HDMI and play on it, it works worse and has huge droops in FPS from time to time, CPU usage is around 20% and it is running at a mere 0.80GHz

Note:
For those thinking that the cable is the problem: the cable works fine in Windows and while doing anything else. It is a gold plated HDMI 2.0 cable.
I have it connected with an adapter from mini Display Port 2 to HDMI 2.0

Comment: Have you tried with a different HDMI cable?

Comment: What version is the HDMI cable you're using?

Comment: I can try but I really don't know how the cable would effect the performance of it displays everything fine, I think it's more to do with some graphics driver or something like that because it runs the game just fine with this cable in Windows.

Comment: There are different versions of a HDMI cable. If the cable has a low bandwidth, it will limit the data that is being transferred, as such a performance decrease can be noticed.

Comment: @LPChip it's a gold plated HDMI 2.0 cable, there is no issue with the image, the rendered frames are dropped, and CPU usage is low, it's 99.9% not the cable

Comment: Well then, have you tried updating your graphics driver?

Comment: mDP->HDMI adapter is another suspect.

Comment: Yes it's the latest graphics driver from Intel's website, I don't think it's the adapter either because it would not effect the actual performance, but would only show a bad image on the screen, however I'm an getting low FPS